# represent the following data in a FlatList or List

Tags: react-native, expo

[image: screenshot of example]Hi i'm trying to make a flat list of the following object I don't seem to understand how the renderItem works because my keys are unique in the FlatList. I tried and got that `Tried to get frame four out of range index NaN` basically need the first object to be the title that onPress can show me the sub objects

```
this.setState({objToDisplay: parsedObj});

// parsedOgj is here 
Object {
   "Mike Smith": Object {
   "1534555555": "Helena",
  },
  "Jack": Object {
     "1553555897": "Cris",
  },
  "mrs bond": Object {
    "10101": "Test Expo",
    "8210": "Tester",
  },
  "test": Object {
    "2222": "Test Expo 2",
    "3333": "Test Expo 3",
  },
}
 <FlatList
      style={styles.list}
      data={this.state.objToDisplay}
      renderItem={({item}) =>()} // would to have Test and then arrow to see the sub object 
    />
```

Comment: You need to pass an array of objects to the flatlist, instead you are passing an object.

Comment: @Andrew I see is there any other way to display this object to the user ?

Comment: It really depends on how you are trying to display the object. It should be possible to refactor the object. Can you give some context in what the objects represent? Do you have any designs that you can show?

Comment: @Andrew I added a small design the first Object will be displayed and on press it will move to represent the sub object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is a code sample showing you one possible way of refactoring the object.  It will give you an out put that is an array like this.

```
[
  {
    title: 'Mike Smith',
    msgs: [{time: '1534555555', name: 'Helena'}]
  }
]
```

```js
let obj = {
  "Mike Smith": {
  "1534555555": "Helena",
  },
  "Jack":  {
    "1553555897": "Cris",
  },
  "mrs bond":  {
    "10101": "Test Expo",
    "8210": "Tester",
  },
  "test":  {
    "2222": "Test Expo 2",
    "3333": "Test Expo 3",
  },
}

// create an array to hold the result, this is what you will eventually save to state
let result = []

// loop over each key in the main object
for (let key in obj) {
  // create a new object with the properties of title and msgs
  let newObj = {}
  newObj.title = key
  newObj.msgs = []

  // get the messages that are in the object
  let messages = obj[key]
  
  // loop over the messages and convert them into their own object with time and name properties
  for (let msg in messages) {
    let message = {}
    message.time = msg
    message.name = messages[msg]

    // push the new messages objects into an array
    newObj.msgs.push(message)
  }
  result.push(newObj)
}

// log out the result so you can see what has been constructed
// ideally you will want to save it to state at this point. 
console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```

I would do any refactoring of the object before adding it into state.

Each row in your FlatList will be passed an item that looks like the one above. You can then render it out in its own way.

Here is a sample component that creates a simple FlatList. When you tap on each row it shows the row's messages in an Alert.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, FlatList, SafeAreaView, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    let obj = {
      "Mike Smith": {
      "1534555555": "Helena",
      },
      "Jack":  {
        "1553555897": "Cris",
      },
      "mrs bond":  {
        "10101": "Test Expo",
        "8210": "Tester",
      },
      "test":  {
        "2222": "Test Expo 2",
        "3333": "Test Expo 3",
      },
    }

    let result = []

    for (let key in obj) {
      let newObj = {}
      newObj.title = key
      newObj.msgs = []

      let messages = obj[key]

      for (let msg in messages) {
        let message = {}
        message.time = msg
        message.name = messages[msg]

        newObj.msgs.push(message)
      }
      result.push(newObj)
    }
    this.setState({data: result})
  }

  renderItem = ({item}) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity 
        style={{height: 70, justifyContent: 'center', borderWidth: 0.5}}
        onPress={() => alert(JSON.stringify(item.msgs))}>
        <Text>{item.title}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }

  keyExtractor = (item, index) => index.toString();

  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={this.state.data}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
        keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
      />
      </SafeAreaView>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to transform your object into an array that can be read by the `FlatList` component, then use the `renderItem` prop to pass a function that will return you the list's components.

Here's an example that gives transform the object into an array and displays the keys as names:

```
obj = {
    'Mike Smith': {
      1534555555: 'Helena',
    },
    Jack: {
      1553555897: 'Cris',
    },
    'mrs bond': {
      10101: 'Test Expo',
      8210: 'Tester',
    },
    test: {
      2222: 'Test Expo 2',
      3333: 'Test Expo 3',
    },
  };

  data = Object.keys(this.obj).map(key => ({
    name: key,
    values: { ...this.obj[key] },
  }));

render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
      data={this.data}
      keyExtractor={item => item.name}
      renderItem={({ item }) => {
        return (
        <View>
          <Text>Name: {item.name}</Text>
        </View>
        );
      }}
      />
    );
  }
```

In this example your data will end up like this:

```js
this.data Array [
   Object {
     "name": "Mike Smith",
     "values": Object {
       "1534555555": "Helena",
     },
   },
   Object {
     "name": "Jack",
     "values": Object {
       "1553555897": "Cris",
     },
   },
   Object {
     "name": "mrs bond",
     "values": Object {
       "10101": "Test Expo",
       "8210": "Tester",
     },
   },
   Object {
     "name": "test",
     "values": Object {
       "2222": "Test Expo 2",
       "3333": "Test Expo 3",
     },
   },
 ]
 item Object {
   "name": "Mike Smith",
   "values": Object {
     "1534555555": "Helena",
   },
 }
 item Object {
   "name": "Jack",
   "values": Object {
     "1553555897": "Cris",
   },
 }
 item Object {
   "name": "mrs bond",
   "values": Object {
     "10101": "Test Expo",
     "8210": "Tester",
   },
 }
 item Object {
   "name": "test",
   "values": Object {
     "2222": "Test Expo 2",
     "3333": "Test Expo 3",
   },
 }
```

If you want the `values` key as an array just change the spread operator to another `map()` and it will work.

From here you can use this structure to create the components you want and show them however you please.